# Transform character feature into numeric

Tags: machine-learning

I have a character feature of weather condition i.e rain, snow...."

I'd like to feed the feature to a random forest, what kind of transformation I can do to turn it into numeric

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a categorical variable into a number by turning the single attribute into n attributes where n is the number of digits necessary to represent the total number of options in binary.

For example, if I have an attribute [weather] that can take the values of "rain","sun","snow" then you could instead create 2 dummy attributes [weather1] and [weather0].  The reason you can do this with 2 dummy attribute is because 3 can be represented in binary with 2 digits: 11.

Then instead of using "rain" you would represent the category as a binary value across the two dummy attributes:
"rain" is first so it would be 01 in binary so that feature would have a 0 for [weather1] and a 1 for [weather0].  "sun" is second so you would represent it as 10 and "snow" is third so you could represent it as 11.  The order isn't important so long as it's consistent across your variables.

If we think of these values as python dictionaries then we can see a more clear example:
feature[weather] = "rain"
new_feature[weather] = [0,1] **or**
new_feature[weather0] = 1, new_feature[weather1] = 0

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't. The weather condition is a categorical variable, which random forest handles natively. Leave it as it is and let the algorithm work as it should.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to convert the text into a categorical value.  Whether the random forest natively handles text as categorical values will depend on what specific implementation they're using.